# How can I generate typescript types for an Emscripten project?

Tags: typescript, emscripten, embind

I don't want to write TypeScript type declaration files for my Emscripten project manually. Is there a way to get such type declaration files generated automatically? Ex. for variables, functions, classes, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's related discussion in this GitHub issue ticket: [Using embind to generate TypeScript typings #7083](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/issues/7083).

[Some support was added to embind around version 3.1.43](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/issues/7083#issuecomment-1634631247). Embind [Docs are here](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/blob/main/site/source/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/embind.rst#typescript-definitions).

> ###### TypeScript Definitions
>
> Embind supports generating TypeScript definition files from [`EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS`](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/blob/main/site/source/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/embind.rst#id80)
> blocks. To generate **.d.ts** files invoke *emcc* with the
> [`embind-emit-tsd <emcc-embind-emit-tsd>`](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/blob/main/site/source/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/embind.rst#id82) option:
>
> ```
> emcc -lembind quick_example.cpp --embind-emit-tsd interface.d.ts
> ```
>
> Running this command will build the program with an instrumented version of embind
> that is then run in *node* to generate the definition files.
> Not all of embind's features are currently supported, but many of the commonly used
> ones are.  Examples of input and output can be seen in [`embind_tsgen.cpp`](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/blob/main/test/other/embind_tsgen.cpp) and
> [`embind_tsgen.d.ts`](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/blob/main/test/other/embind_tsgen.d.ts).

Other related functionality is still pending at the time of this writing:

- [embind typescript - generate class property definitions #19855](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/issues/19855) ([now completed](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/pull/19875))
- [embind typescript - generate static class functions definitions #19856](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/issues/19856) ([now completed](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/issues/19856#event-9979883762))
- [embind typescript - generate memory views definitions #19857](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/issues/19857)

---

There are also some Emscripten-external projects that others in the community have made, each with their own interfaces and some limitations:

- https://github.com/charto/nbind/blob/master/bin/ndts.js
- https://github.com/ted537/tsembind
- https://github.com/marczellm/emscripdtsgen